# Error while defining String constant

Tags: java

Given:

```
public static final String XML_POLICY =
            "<?xml version="1.0"?>"
            +"<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">"
            + "<cross-domain-policy>"
            + "<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />"
            + "</cross-domain-policy>";
```

I am getting compile errors on the

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>"
```

it says '`;`' expected.

and on

```
+"<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">"
```

it says "cannot find symbol, symbol: class xml and class dtds"

What could be the possible cause? IDE is Netbeans 6.8 Beta.

Comment: same behaviour (not a bug) on netbeans 6.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes - and it's not just the first line, either. The doctype and allow-access-from lines require it too.

```
// Reformatted slightly to avoid scrolling :)
public static final String XML_POLICY =
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
  + "<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">"
  + "<cross-domain-policy>"
  + "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />"
  + "</cross-domain-policy>";
```

An alternative it to use single quotes within the XML, which is fine in most places, and makes the code simpler to read:

```
public static final String XML_POLICY =
    "<?xml version='1.0'?>"
    +"<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM '/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd'>"
    + "<cross-domain-policy>"
    + "<allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='*' />"
    + "</cross-domain-policy>";
```

Note that there's nothing Netbeans or XML-specific about this. A double quote is used to indicate the start and end of a string, which is why you need to escape it if you want one in the middle. For example:

```
String x = "I said, \"Hello.\" The child laughed.";
```

There are various other escape sequences in Java - see [section 3.10.6 of the language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6) for more details.

Comment: Wish I could do a +10 on this!

Answer (score 2):

you must escape the " inside the string:

```
public static final String XML_POLICY =     
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + // etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

[read the section on escape sequences](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is well answered, but just a note/hint:
thanks to syntax highlighting, part of the text should be coloured differently indicating that it's not part of the literal.
Netbeans *must* have syntax highlighting enabled (default?). Stackoverflow also has syntax highlighting, just look at the code in the question (above).